# Timed Item Spawn in MineCraft Chests

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

I'm looking to set up "incentives" for exploring different areas on my minecraft SMP server.

One idea I had was for items to spawn in chests scattered in out of the way areas that spawn harder to find items every certain interval if the chest is empty. So for example, a chest might spawn a diamond pick once every 48 hours if it doesn't already have a pick. (so a person doesn't happen upon a chest full of diamond picks)

Are there any bukkit plugins that support this, or some combination of plugins that would allow me to do this?

Comment: Interesting idea. I think, though, it'd be even cooler if the items would just be 'dropped items' that never despawned. That would be awesome! I'm going to try to make that. I'll post here if I finish.

Comment: I would seriously love if you made this, haha. However I would caution you on "dropped" items as that creates more entities for the server to monitor.

Comment: True, but I assume it wouldn't be THAT many items, and it would only display them on loaded chunks. Also, I've started work on this, but I'm not 100% sure when I'll be done.

Answer (score 2):

I've done a bit of research, and there's no mod exactly like the one you describe (which amazes me, it looks like a great idea!).

As for alternative approaches, I think you're best off using a shopping/economy mod, such as [RealShop](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/econ-realshop-v0-70-shop-using-chests-1000.5613/), which allows a chest to be set up as a 'shop', where players can put in 'currency', e.g. gold, and then take out as many of the item in the shop chest as they can afford.

By choosing the item you use as currency carefully (and by carefully setting prices) you can get a similar 'exploration reward' system set up.

Comment: As soon as I get some time I'm probably going to write my own mod for this. It's pretty much a perfect fit for my server, but I'm assuming that the bukkit API is going to change with MC 1.8 that's due any day soon, so I'll likely build the mod after that. Or, if I'm feeling generous, I might just hire somebody to make this mod for me, lol.

Answer (score 0):

This could have worked

http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/fun-junkstreasurehunt-v1-11-treasure-hunts-for-minecraft-935.20897/

But I think it's not working for Bukkit [1000]